# Two figurative meanings of using raft in expressions

Tags: phrase-request

In my language, if I say “he’s gone with the raft” it means, figuratively, that he’s insane.

On the other hand, if I say “do you think I came with the raft?” or “do you think I came on the straw through the pipe” it means that I’m not that stupid as you think.

I would like to know if such expressions exist in English not necessarily to use this particular word “raft” or “straw”.

Would you please help me with your replies?

Comment: In US English, one would say: > He's gone crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Maulik V](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3187/maulik-v) points out, the English expression closest to “do you think I came with the raft?” is “do you think I was born yesterday?”

> **not be born yesterday**
>  <sup>INFORMAL</sup>
>  to not be stupid or easy to deceive:
> *You don't fool me - I wasn't born yesterday.*
> <sub>Source: [Cambridge Dictionaries Online – definition for “not be born yesterday”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/not-be-born-yesterday?q=born+yesterday)</sub>

There is the expression [“fresh off the boat”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresh_off_the_boat) in English, but this is a derogatory term for someone who is naïve with regards to local customs, not someone you mean to suggest is stupid or insane.

---

There are many expressions for suggesting insanity. Here's a popular one:

> **have a screw loose**
>  <sup>INFORMAL</sup>
> If you say that someone has a screw loose, you mean that they behave in a strange way and seem slightly mentally ill.
> <sub>Source: [Cambridge Dictionaries Online – definition for “have a screw loose”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/have-a-screw-loose)</sub>

Another commonly employed metaphor is the suggestion that someone has “lost his marbles”.

> **lose your marbles**
>  <sup>INFORMAL HUMOROUS</sup>
> to become crazy
> <sub>Source: [Cambridge Dictionaries Online – definition for “lose your marbles”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/lose-your-marbles?q=+lose++your++marbles)</sub>

---

For a vulgar slang expression for “crazy”, activate the ‘spoiler’ in the space below:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It’s really what I expected.

Answer (score 2):

The simple thing without any ambiguity is:

***He has gone mad.***

> [gone mad](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gone+mad) - affected with madness or **insanity** (your translation); "a man who had gone mad"

Similarly, if you want others to know that you are not stupid, you may simply say:

***Do you think I was born yesterday?***

> [I/he/she wasn't born yesterday!](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+wasn%27t+born+yesterday!) - something that you say in order to tell someone that a **person is not stupid** (your translation) and cannot be easily deceived

Comment: @snailplane - so quick! I reread my answer and was just clicking on 'edit' meanwhile you did it! :)

Comment: Yeah, even quicker was snailplane!